# `id` NOT NULL auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I have MySQL 5.0 installed on my server. The SQL auto increment is not working. I've defined column with auto increment but still not working, it says:

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
```

Comment: Just as error mesage says, empty string is not proper value for integer column.

Comment: show your insert statement and table definition

Answer (score 2):

Insert NULL in the primary key column instead of empty string. From the error I can see that you are trying to insert "" value.

Comment: Or just don't insert anything into that column, since that's the whole point of auto-increment...

Comment: But if you want to use short version of insert [INSERT INTO table (value1, value2 ...)] without enumerating columns, you have to put NULL into primary key column.

Comment: Perhaps, but I never rely any database engine figuring out what columns I'm mapping to; doing so makes your code brittle. Regardless, your answer is correct. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be

```
INSERT INTO myTable(col2, col3) VALUES('x','y');
```

Omitting the auto increment column

Answer (score 0):

i just use DEFAULT instead of ""

INSERT INTO User VALUES ( DEFAULT, '$Username', ... )

that auto increments for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your primary key is something along the lines of:

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

I have used:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `foo`, `hello`) VALUES ('', 'bar', 'world')
```

Putting a blank string in the key works if the key is setup like mine.  This may be a bad practice, but I know it works so if it isn't working for you then I'd say maybe you missed something when you created your table.

Omitting the `id` in your INSERT is most likely the most appropriate method and using NULL is probably second best.  I don't have any documentation to back that up, but just as an observation, that seems like it would probably be the case.